# Please provide an alternative for DB visualiser for handling netezza database

Tags: database, netezza

currently i use db visualiser for connecting the netezza database. can you suggest any otehr alternative (freeware) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Aginity Netezza Workbench www.aginity.com.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-database-explorer/) project.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything better than DBVis. Make sure you are using the loaded JDBC drivers for netezza instead of the ODBC data source.

I broke down and got the paid version. very good stuff. You can run multiple query windows and explorers at once.

Other software includes RazorSQL or any number of other softwares like SQLassistant, SQLdeveloper, etc can be setup to run against netezza.